# Left and Right Indent in Same SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I need to to be able to control the alignment of text in the expression. What I need is for a $ to always  be left indented but then put the value right indented. 
Example:

```
$     100.00
$          -
$ 546,983.00
$    4567,00
```

The dash is what is required for 0.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way you can achieve this is to use multiple text boxes. A small one just big enough for the $ and another which is right aligned for the amount. You could make it easier to manipulate if you put them both inside a rectangle.